# Assembly system time DOS

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I wrote some code:

```
petla:
mov ah,2
int 1ah

mov[sekunda], dh
mov ah, [sekunda]
mov cl, 4
and ah, 11110000b 
shr ah, cl  
mov dl, ah
add dl, '0'
mov ah, 2
int 21h

mov ah, [sekunda]
and ah, 00001111b   
mov dl, ah
add dl, '0'
mov ah, 2
int 21h

jmp petla

sekunda db 0
```

When I run this program shows me lot of values (seconds) looks like this:

```
12
12
12
12
12
13
13
```

How modify code to show only one time one values ( one seconds one value)?

How I can modify code to show for example time every 5 sec?

I need this to my main code where after x seconds  something will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that seconds are **very** long periods of time for a computer (Well, for the last 40-50 years at least!)

Your little program is grabbing the time value very quickly, so it can get the current time several thousand (million even!) times a second.

If you only want an output when it changes, try something like the following:  (We're adding a comparison)

```
petla:
    mov ah,2
    int 1ah             ; get time

    mov ah, [sekunda]   ; retrieve last good value
    cmp ah, dh          ; is it same as last good value?
    jz  pet1a           ; yup, ignore it, loop again!

    mov [sekunda], dh   ; save seconds

    mov ah, [sekunda]   ; get seconds value
    mov cl, 4           ; ready to shift 4 bits
    and ah, 11110000b   ; isolate top nybble
    shr ah, cl          ; shift into low nybble
    mov dl, ah          ; move into proper register for output
    add dl, '0'         ; magically transform into ASCII digit
    mov ah, 2           ; Select 'write char'
    int 21h             ; uh... write char!

    mov ah, [sekunda]   ; hey, this seems familiar!
    and ah, 00001111b   ; isolate lower nybble!
    mov dl, ah          ; no, really.. deja vu!
    add dl, '0'         ; TaaDaa, it's a char!
    mov ah, 2           ; Select 'write char'
    int 21h             ; make it so!

    jmp petla           ; do it again!  (make this a 'ret', see below)
```

Now this little routine will constantly output a new value every second... perhaps not very valuable...

But wait!  There's more!

If you change the LAST instruction (`jmp pet1a`) to a return (`ret`), we can use it as part of a 'wait_for_five_seconds' routine... like so:

```
wait_for_five_seconds:
    mov al,5              ; how many seconds to wait
wait_for_al_seconds:      ; explained below
wait_loop:
    push ax               ; save our counter (al)
    call pet1a            ; this will call pet1a, which will not return until it has displayed a new second value
    pop ax                ; retrieve our counter (pet1a changes value of ah/al/ax, remember?)
    dec al                ; decrease al by one (does not set flags!!)
    or al,al              ; set flags
    jnz wait_loop         ; al=0?  nope, around we go again!
    ret                   ; go back to whomever called us!
```

Now, if you wanted to pause for 5 seconds, you simple call `wait_for_five_seconds` and it'll work!

If you remove the part of pet1a that writes the characters out... you then have a **silent** delay of one second.  Useful for pausing.

What if you wanted to pause for 17 seconds?   Hmmm, our delay is based on the value of `al` when we enter the `wait_loop` section... so what if we preloaded `al`, then called the wait bit?

```
    mov al, 17                 ; delay for 17 seconds!
    call wait_for_al_seconds   ; delay for whatever number is in al
```

Be careful though, if `al` has a value of 0... it has to loop all the way around... 0, -1, -2, ... -127, -128, 127, 126... 2, 1, 0 ... you'd pause for 256 seconds! (4 minutes, 16 seconds!).  (See [Signed Number Representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) for why it went weird around -128)

I hope this has helped and perhaps given you some ideas.  It's not an idea 'pause' solution since it isn't an exact delay, if you called `pet1a` **just** before a new second ticked over, the delay would be teeny-tiny for the first click, then full seconds for the rest... so a desired delay of 5 seconds could be anywhere from 4.000001 seconds to 5 seconds long.  But it's a start.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit this isn't the best code, nor the best __way__ to pause or delay.  But considering the OP's original code and platform, I figured we're learning and need a little guidance.  Like I said, hopefully you will get ideas and try other things too, programming is amazing, and assembly programming is amazinger! (Yes, I do quite a bit of assembly programming, various platforms)

Comment: I still got problem with delay I change last line `jmp petla  ` to  `call wait_for_five_seconds` but still got delay 1 seconds not 5

Comment: no... last line to `ret`, somewhere ELSE, `call wait_for_five_seconds`.  Read it again. :)